# Posting questions about a hypothetical Christian denomination that MAY agree with a view

Tags: discussion

Under what circumstances can we post questions about [a hypothetical Christian denomination that *may* agree with a position](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/37162/are-there-any-christian-groups-which-teach-that-god-is-male-and-female)?

I have a feeling that such a denomination does not exist. However, I don't want to marginalize denominations or people who actually hold such a belief, however unknown they may be to our current understanding of Christianity. Who knows? Maybe there is one Christian or one group of Christians somewhere in the middle of nowhere that believes that God is both male AND female instead of *transcending gender* or being neither male nor female. There are real denominations that believe that God is masculine and feminine, but this may not suggest that God is a hermaphrodite. Being a hermaphrodite is not the same as being agender or asexual (biological sense).

What do you think? What do we do about these types of questions?

Answer (score 5):

Hypotheticals are usually a waste of everyone's time. There are an infinite number of hypothetical questions! So instead of simply asking whether any groups teach that God is male and female, show some kind of evidence which makes you think it is more likely than not. FMS improved that question hugely by adding in a quote from Wikipedia. (As always, Wikipedia is terrible, except for everything else.) Now it's a reasonable question.

(Now I personally think the quote from Wikipedia is junk. That Wikipedia page could do with a lot more editing. But for the purpose of questions on this site, it suffices.)